# How not to get a gtkdrawingarea cleared in the draw event?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, pycairo

My drawingarea is cleared everytime the draw event is called.
How to avoid a drawingarea to be cleared ?

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo
import math

class MouseButtons:
    LEFT_BUTTON = 1
    RIGHT_BUTTON = 3

class Example(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):    

        self.darea = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.darea.connect("draw", self.on_draw)
        self.darea.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)        

        self.add(self.darea)

        self.set_title("Fill & stroke")
        self.resize(230, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.darea.connect("button-press-event", self.on_button_press)

        self.coords = []
        self.show_all()

    def on_draw(self, wid, cr):

        cr.set_source_rgb(0.6, 0.6, 0.6)
        cr.arc(self.coords[0], self.coords[1], 40, 0, 2*math.pi)
        cr.fill()

    def on_button_press(self, w, e):

        if e.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS \
            and e.button == MouseButtons.LEFT_BUTTON:
            self.coords = [e.x, e.y]

        self.darea.queue_draw()           

def main():
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

In this example, each time I click on the drawingarea, a circle is drawn. I would like to draw the new circle but without to redrawing the previous one.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adjusting your mental model of the drawing area; don't think of it as being "cleared" every time the draw handler is called. Rather, think of it like this: the draw handler is called every time the drawing area needs to be redrawn from scratch (among other reasons: because some other window moved in front of it, or because your program asked for a draw update). The drawing area's contents, once drawn, are not persisted anywhere.

If you need persistent window contents, then you should use a backing store and draw that onto the screen in the draw handler, or you could use a canvas library if you want to treat existing drawn objects as independently existing.

Answer (score 0):

I found he answer :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo
import math

class MouseButtons:
    LEFT_BUTTON = 1
    RIGHT_BUTTON = 3

class Example(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):    

        self.darea = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.darea.connect("draw", self.on_draw)
        self.darea.set_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)        

        self.add(self.darea)

        self.set_title("Fill & stroke")
        self.resize(230, 150)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.darea.connect("button-press-event", self.on_button_press)
        self.show_all()

        a = self.darea.get_allocation()
        print (a.x, a.y, a.width, a.height)
        self.img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.Format.RGB24, a.width, a.height)

    def on_draw(self, wid, cr):
        cr.set_source_surface(self.img, 0, 0)
        cr.paint()

    def on_button_press(self, w, e):
        if e.type == Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS \
            and e.button == MouseButtons.LEFT_BUTTON:
            cr = cairo.Context(self.img)
            cr.set_source_rgb(0.6, 0.6, 0.6)
            cr.arc(e.x, e.y, 40, 0, 2*math.pi)
            cr.fill()

        self.darea.queue_draw()           

def main():
    app = Example()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```